# Personalize browser version of email

Tags: email

I'm trying to figure out how to get the browser version of an email to match an email using tokens in terms of personalization. The email shows the person's first and last name, the opt out and unsubscribe links, and the link to the browser version.

for example, the url for the opt out link in the browser version loses the id # as shown below. Same problem with the unsubscribe link. The first and last name also disappears.

Email version (with dummy IDs): `https://mydomain.ca/civicrm/mailing/optout?reset=1&jid=5555&qid=55555&h=a5aa5a5aa555aa5a`

Browser version: `https://mydomain.ca/civicrm/mailing/optout?reset=1&jid=&qid=&h=`

Any suggestions on keeping the personalization in the browser version?

Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, I would consider a method for hiding the links and replacing it with generic instructions for editing mail preferences through their profile. The main thing is to not have non-functional links in the web version.

Comment: I dont know exactly how to solve this but I would think that you need a link with the checksum in it. There is a token for the checksum.

Also did you had a look at https://docs.civicrm.org?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is recorded here: 
https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1064

And there is currently some work being done on this here:
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/14591

If you are keen to get this merged into core recommend testing it and commenting on the PR.